# Error installing repo command. Help please?!! Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I'm trying to install the repo command so I can compile CyanogenMod for my phone but whenever i enter the command:

```
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

I get an error saying:

```
bash: /home/r0b458/bin/repo: Permission denied
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Does your home directory contain a directory called `bin`?

Comment: @chronitis ha I thought of the same but curl states "No such file or directory" when there is no "bin/" :D

Answer (score 0):

Is r0b458 your user name? I assume it is not: since the error notice probably means your are not and when putting files onto your system in a location that is not owned by you you need to use `sudo`.

```
sudo curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

By the way: your command works on my system when I am logged in as rinzwind:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ mkdir bin
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 23618  100 23618    0     0   113k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  113k
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ cd bin
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/bin$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 23618 dec 14 21:30 repo
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/bin$
```

If you forget to include the ~ in front of /bin/repo at the end of the command that would error it out with a permission denied. Otherwise I would assume it should work as shown above.

Comment: That is my username and I tried to do the command with sudo as well

Comment: Might you have forgotten to include the ~ in front of /bin/repo? That would error it out with a permission denied.

Comment: @chrontis yes I have a directory in my home folder called bin and it's weird cause i typed su and gave it my password and entered the command again and it said no such file or directory

Comment: I copied and pasted it into the terminal

Comment: wait wait. su? That makes you root and the is no /home/root/bin ;) You need 'sudo'

Comment: I tried sudo first and that didn't work because it said permission denied like how it says in the original question

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir ~/bin

PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Source: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

It was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

If you check permission of `/bin/`. Then, you will see that it is accessible for root user.

[image]

So, there's three way to save file to bin directory.

1. Make the /bin/repo permission to public

   `sudo chmod 777 /bin/repo`
   #Then, you can do as you did
2. You can run curl command with sudo command

   `sudo curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo`

sudo works as a root user.

3. Works as a root user.

   `sudo su`

   `curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo`

If you don't have repo directory in `bin` directory. Than, above command may not work. That's why you have to create a directory called `repo` in `bin`.

```
sudo mkdir /bin/repo
```